# Combining ListFragment and Fragment with a TabsPagerAdapter which only accepts fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a TabsPagerAdapter which only allows me to call Fragments, so I can't call a ListFragment

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new InformacionFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new ProductosFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new MoviesFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}}
```

This is ProductosFragment, where I want to set the ListFragment:

```
public class ProductosFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.zfragment_conjunta, container, false);

                                                        }
                                                }
```

And this is the ListFragment I want to include: http://pastebin.com/AXuXWvmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it, I wasn't using Android Support v4 for importing Fragments, with this lines in import I fixed it, allowing to return a ListFragment instead a Fragment

In TabsPagerAdapter:

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;`

In ListFragment class:

`import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;`

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste any error logs you have? But are you trying to include ListFragment within a Fragment, if yes why? Just directly include the ListFragment as it's just a fragment with an empty list.

Try to replace :

case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new ProductosFragment();

with

case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new ConjuntaFragment();

Comment: here you have: Error:(25, 24) incompatible types
found   : com.ivanmz.forotek.app.ConjuntaFragment
required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: i'm really not sure about your problem but did you import android.support.v4.app.Fragment in ConjuntaFragment. and also did you try to just directly Show conjunctaFragment as i recommended earlier?

Comment: Yes, I tried before I posted here my problem, but the problem is that in the TabsPagerAdapter needs to be a class extended to Fragment and in ConjuntaFragment(); is extended to ListFragment, if I extend it to Fragment it doesn't fails on the TabsPagerReader but the List fails.